# Origin Cache-Control not working on AWS Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I am serving my images using AWS Cloudfront. Origin images headers include Cache-Control settings but these header are not being transfered to AWS. I have checked the AWS documentation and I think that my Cloudfront settings are correct:

> Settings Object Caching: Use Origin Cache Headers

I have created a page where you can see the same image, loaded directly from its origin, and loaded by Cloudfront. As you can see, the second image doesn't include the Cache-Control header setting:

https://www.fanaticguitars.com/cache-control-test.php

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misconfiguration is on your server, not on CloudFront.

If I connect to your `www` server but then lie to it and tell it I'm asking for `img` rather than `www` by setting the HTTP `Host:` header (which is what CloudFront is doing when it fetches content, if you have the `Host:` header whitelisted in the cache behavior), **your server doesn't return `Cache-Control` headers in this case** even though it does (twice!) when the request is targeted to `www`.

This is a connection to your server, not to CloudFront:

```
$ curl -v https://www.fanaticguitars.com/v2/avatar.png -H 'Host: img.fanaticguitars.com' > /dev/null

> GET /v2/avatar.png HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Accept: */*
> Host: img.fanaticguitars.com
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Thu, 09 Mar 2017 16:49:31 GMT
< Content-Type: image/png
< Content-Length: 9915
< Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Mar 2017 21:46:59 GMT
< Connection: close
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
* Closing connection #0
```